# Limiting behavior of the ridge regression estimator as $\lambda \to \infty$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, ridge-regression

I am a bit confused about a few aspects of the behavior of the ridge regression estimator as $\lambda \to \infty$ (see photos below).

The facts that the bias is $- \lambda (\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X + \lambda \mathbf I)^{-1}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, and the limit of the ridge estimator is zero imply that

\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} - \lambda (\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X + \lambda \mathbf I)^{-1} = \mathbf I,
\end{align}

right?

If my understanding is correct, the bias is a vector, and the limit of the bias is $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, so then is the squared bias actually the number $\boldsymbol{\beta}^\top \boldsymbol{\beta}$?

Thanks for any help.

**Photo 1:**

[image]

---

**Photo 2 (see especially highlighted portion):**

[image]

Comment: The highlighted (purple) portion at the end answers your question.  What additional information would you be looking for?

Comment: @whuber Maybe it's a basic error, but when it says $\boldsymbol{\beta}^\top \boldsymbol{\beta}$ is the squared bias of the estimator (in the limit), I thought that meant the bias (in the limit) is the length of the vector, i.e. $\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\beta}^\top \boldsymbol{\beta}}$. But then the bias calculations didn't make sense. The only choice that seems sensible is what I've written above, but I'm not confident in it. I guess I'm asking this: if you replace question marks with periods in what I wrote above, is it correct?